# installing Closure Compiler on debian Nginx

Tags: javascript, nginx, compression, minify, google-closure-compiler

I was searching over the internet to find a good document about how to install Closure Compiler from google on my Debian Nginx server, and got nothing. all I got so far is [Closure Compiler](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/?csw=1). I want to install this tool to compress and minify both css and js files independently so that these static files get lighter on page load when requested.

Is there any good source how to do that?

all I find is about Yui compressor which is not as good as Closure Compiler as I read.

any thoughts on that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure Compiler does not minify CSS files, just JS files.  For that you want: https://github.com/google/closure-stylesheets

Closure Compiler isn't a good choice if you want to minify arbitrary JS files without testing the result.  It doesn't back off when faced with eval or with or IE's conditional code like some other compression tools do.

If you are using Apache perhaps you might like [Google's PageSpeed module](http://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) which is designed to work in the general case.

Comment: is there a better alternative?

Comment: A better alternative for what?

Comment: to minify and compress js files or even css files, too.

Comment: It really depends on what you are trying to do.  Just removing whitespace from a JS file can break some libraries.  But perhaps you want: https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module

Comment: Updated answer with the PageSpeed link